# Why did date ordinality calculations change in iOS 12?

Tags: ios, nsdate, ios12

Try the following in playgrounds. Before iOS 12, it worked for all inputs (starting with 1):

input would equal output

```
let input = 1

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.day = input
dateComponents.hour = 0
dateComponents.minute = 0
dateComponents.second = 0

let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
let output = Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .day, in: .era, for: date2!)

assert(output==input)
```

But, now in iOS 12, output and input will only be equal starting with an input of 577738... which is date: Oct 17, 1582, which is two days after the Gregorian calendar went into effect (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)

So, what's going on here? And why did this change in iOS 12?